# NullPointerException while changing textcolor of listview item

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

Overriding the getView method to change the textcolor of the list item -

```
 aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return view;
        }
    } ;
```

Logcat :

```
-Process: com.example.sairav.app3, PID: 1470
    ***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.sairav.app3.MainActivity$1.getView(MainActivity.java:38)***
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.onLayout(AbsoluteLayout.java:123)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time getView is invoked, convertView is null. Calling the super and assigning its return value to view, leaves convertView not initialized, hence the crash.

```
 convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
 TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
 tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 return convertView;
```

Edit:

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` contains only a `TextView`, so instead to use findViewById, you can cast the return value of `super.getView`

```
convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
((TextView)convertView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 return convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

//  use view instead of convertview

```
       TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
    }
} ;
```